# create select statement based on case statement in sql

Tags: sql

Is there a clean way in sql to create a select statement based on a case statement?

I'm looking for the basic logic to be something like

```
   CASE @tableToUse
           WHEN 'Table1' SELECT * FROM Table1 
           WHEN 'Table2' SELECT * FROM table2 
           DEFAULT 'Table3' SELECT * FROM table3
   END CASE
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this query? Can you provide example data and expected output?

Comment: I'm only trying to see if it is possible to execute a select on a different table based on a case.

Comment: So are you just looking for a clean way of doing a load of if..else logic?

Comment: You might want to update your example to reflect that.

Comment: You can do this by wrapping the then select in parentheses, see Astro's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In T-Sql (MS SQL Server) you can dynamically compose your SQL statement and then use the [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) method to execute it.  Based on your case statement you can build a SELECT statement using a variable and then use sp_executesql to run it.  The one thing to be aware of is that you need to make sure you clean any input you get from users if you are using text directly from users to prevent SQL injection attacks.

For example,

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(200)

SELECT @sql = CASE @tableToUse
    WHEN 'Table1' THEN 'SELECT * FROM Table1'
    WHEN 'Table2' THEN 'SELECT * FROM Table2'
    ELSE 'Table3' THEN 'SELECT * FROM Table2'
    END

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

You should be able to do something similar in other versions of SQL.

Comment: Of course this is the required reading if you plan to use dynamic SQL
http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Answer (score 5):

Well, this is old, but in case it is helpful:

```
CASE WHEN <Variabe> THEN (SELECT <Column> FROM <Table>) END
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, Case statements in tSQL  (which I assume you are asking about) are for evaluating expressions only and can't be used for control flow.

You are pretty much stuck with IF..THEN

```
IF (@Something='Table1')
    SELECT Field1 from table1
ELSE
   IF (@Something='Table2')
        SELECT Field1 from table2
   ELSE
        SELECT Field1 From table3
```

Comment: @downvoter: Don't shoot the messenger. I didn't write the tSQL language.

Comment: + 1 This is the correct answer, if OP wants static SQL and if OP is using SQL Server (T-SQL). Static SQL does have some advantages versus using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just join to the testTable on username?

Comment: I see that would make sense for the example I gave above. But just for educational purposes I want to know how to execute a select based on the results from a case statement.

Comment: I could only answer the question you asked. Since you have changed the question, go with JohnFx or TLiebe's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this ! only that you cannot do a "select *" as that might return more than one value that shoot an error even if that has to be a table with a single column

```
SELECT   columnName = CASE WHEN 'foo' THEN select <Column_Name> from tableName where columnName = 'this'  
                           WHEN 'bar' THEN select <Column_Name>  from tableName where columnName = 'that' 
END 
FROM tableName
```